Proving the linear count slope-search algorithm in Dafny
I've been working to implement a slope search algorithm in Dafny where I have a double ascending matrix, and I want to calculate the amount of elements strictly less than a given value. Besides the O(NM) algorithm, I'm looking to implement the linear algorithm. I've gone ahead and implemented a predicate which ensures the matrix is double sorted
I've also fully solved the problem on paper, and have landed on the following pseudo code for it, which I've fully proven formally to be correct.
const m, n, w, matrix;
var x, y, z;

z := 0;
x := 0;
y := n;

while x < m && y > 0 do
  if matrix[y-1][x] < w then 
    z := z + y;
    x := x + 1;
  else
    y := y - 1;
  end;
end;

In Dafny, I've setup the following predicate for a double sorted matrix:
predicate AscAsc(a: array2<int>)
  reads a
{
  (forall i, j, k:: 0 <= i < j < a.Length0 && 0 <= k < a.Length1 ==> a[i,k] <= a[j,k]) &&
  (forall i, j, k:: 0 <= i < a.Length0 && 0 <= j < k < a.Length1 ==> a[i,j] <= a[i,k])
}

After making a couple utility functions and playing around I managed to land on this implementation, which fully passes Dafny.
predicate AscAsc(a: array2<int>)
  reads a
{
  (forall i, j, k:: 0 <= i < j < a.Length0 && 0 <= k < a.Length1 ==> a[i,k] <= a[j,k]) &&
  (forall i, j, k:: 0 <= i < a.Length0 && 0 <= j < k < a.Length1 ==> a[i,j] <= a[i,k])
}

function CountInColumn(a: array2<int>, col:int, ylo: int, yhi: int, value: int): int
  requires 0 <= col < a.Length1
  requires 0 <= ylo <= yhi <= a.Length0
  requires AscAsc(a)
  decreases yhi-ylo
  reads a
{
  if(ylo == yhi) then 0
  else if(a[ylo,col] < value) then 1+CountInColumn(a,col,ylo+1,yhi,value)
  else CountInColumn(a,col,ylo+1,yhi,value)
}

function CountInRow(a: array2<int>, row:int, xlo: int, xhi: int, value: int): int
  requires 0 <= row < a.Length0
  requires 0 <= xlo <= xhi <= a.Length1
  requires AscAsc(a)
  decreases xhi-xlo
  reads a
{
  if(xlo == xhi) then 0
  else if(a[row,xlo] < value) then 1+CountInRow(a,row,xlo+1,xhi,value)
  else CountInRow(a,row,xlo+1,xhi,value)
}

lemma CountInMatrixRowLemma(a: array2<int>, xlo: int, xhi: int, ylo: int, yhi: int, value: int)
  requires 0 <= xlo <= xhi <= a.Length1
  requires 0 <= ylo <= yhi <= a.Length0
  requires AscAsc(a)
  requires yhi - ylo == 1
  decreases xhi-xlo
  ensures CountInMatrix(a,xlo,xhi,ylo,yhi,value) == CountInRow(a,ylo,xlo,xhi,value)
{
  if(xlo == xhi) {
    assert CountInMatrix(a,xlo,xhi,ylo,yhi,value) == 0;
    assert CountInRow(a,ylo,xlo,xhi,value) == 0;
  } else {
    assert CountInMatrix(a,xlo,xhi,ylo,yhi,value) == CountInColumn(a,xlo,ylo,yhi,value) + CountInMatrix(a,xlo+1,xhi,ylo,yhi,value);
    assert CountInRow(a,ylo,xlo,xhi,value) == CountInColumn(a,xlo,ylo,yhi,value) + CountInRow(a,ylo,xlo+1,xhi,value);
    CountInMatrixRowLemma(a, xlo+1, xhi, ylo, yhi, value);
  }
}

lemma RowEmptyLemma(a: array2<int>, row:int, xlo: int, xhi: int, value: int)
  requires AscAsc(a)
  requires 0 <= row < a.Length0
  requires 0 <= xlo <= xhi <= a.Length1
  requires forall k:: xlo <= k < xhi ==> a[row,k] >= value
  ensures CountInRow(a,row,xlo,xhi,value) == 0
  decreases xhi-xlo
{
  if(xlo == xhi) {
    assert CountInRow(a,row,xlo,xhi,value) == 0;
  } else {
    assert CountInRow(a,row,xlo,xhi,value) == CountInRow(a,row,xlo+1,xhi,value);
    RowEmptyLemma(a, row, xlo+1, xhi, value);
  }
}

lemma CountInMatrixSingleColumnLemma(a: array2<int>, x: int, y: int, value: int)
  requires 0 <= x < a.Length1
  requires 0 < y <= a.Length0
  requires AscAsc(a)
  decreases y
  requires a[y-1,x] < value
  requires forall k:: 0 <= k < y - 1 ==> a[k,x] < value
  ensures CountInMatrix(a, x, x + 1, 0, y, value) == y;

lemma CountInMatrixSplitRuleLemma(a: array2<int>, xlo: int, xhi: int, ylo: int, yhi: int, value: int)
  requires 0 <= xlo <= xhi <= a.Length1
  requires 0 <= ylo < yhi <= a.Length0
  requires AscAsc(a)
  ensures CountInMatrix(a, xlo, xhi, ylo, yhi, value) == CountInMatrix(a, xlo, xhi, ylo, yhi - 1, value) +
                                                         CountInMatrix(a, xlo, xhi, yhi - 1, yhi, value);

function CountInMatrix(a: array2<int>, xlo: int, xhi: int, ylo: int, yhi: int, value: int): int
  requires 0 <= xlo <= xhi <= a.Length1
  requires 0 <= ylo <= yhi <= a.Length0
  requires AscAsc(a)
  decreases xhi-xlo
  reads a
{
  if(xlo == xhi) then 0
  else if(ylo == yhi) then 0
  else
    CountInColumn(a,xlo,ylo,yhi,value) + CountInMatrix(a,xlo+1,xhi,ylo,yhi,value)
}

function CountInMatrixRow(a: array2<int>, xlo: int, xhi: int, ylo: int, yhi: int, value: int): int
  requires 0 <= xlo <= xhi <= a.Length1
  requires 0 <= ylo <= yhi <= a.Length0
  requires AscAsc(a)
  decreases yhi-ylo
  reads a
{
  if(xlo == xhi) then 0
  else if(ylo == yhi) then 0
  else if(yhi - ylo == 1) then CountInRow(a,ylo,xlo,xhi,value)
  else
    CountInRow(a,ylo,xlo,xhi,value) + CountInMatrixRow(a,xlo,xhi,ylo+1,yhi,value)
}

method StudentImplementation(a: array2<int>, value: int) returns (z: int)
  requires AscAsc(a)
  requires a.Length0 > 0 && a.Length1 > 0
  ensures z == CountInMatrix(a,0,a.Length1,0,a.Length0,value)
{
  z := 0;
  var x := 0;
  var y := a.Length0;
  assert  z + CountInMatrix(a, x, a.Length1, 0, y, value) == CountInMatrix(a, 0, a.Length1, 0, a.Length0, value);
  while(x < a.Length1 && y > 0)
    invariant 0 <= x <= a.Length1
    invariant 0 <= y <= a.Length0
    invariant z + CountInMatrix(a, x, a.Length1, 0, y, value) == CountInMatrix(a, 0, a.Length1, 0, a.Length0, value)
  {

    if(a[y - 1,x] < value) {
      assert CountInMatrix(a, x, a.Length1, 0, y, value) == CountInMatrix(a, x, x+1, 0, y, value) + CountInMatrix(a, x+1, a.Length1, 0, y, value);

      CountInMatrixSingleColumnLemma(a, x, y, value);
      assert CountInMatrix(a, x, x+1, 0, y, value) == y;

      z := z + y;
      x := x + 1;
    } else {
      RowEmptyLemma(a, y-1, x, a.Length1, value);
      CountInMatrixRowLemma(a, x, a.Length1, y-1, y, value);
      assert CountInMatrix(a, x, a.Length1, y-1, y, value) == 0;

      CountInMatrixSplitRuleLemma(a, x, a.Length1, 0, y, value);
      assert CountInMatrix(a, x, a.Length1, 0, y, value) == CountInMatrix(a, x, a.Length1, y-1, y, value) +
                                                            CountInMatrix(a, x, a.Length1, 0, y-1, value);
      y := y - 1;
    }
  }
}

Everything in this implementation passes Dafny, however it relies on these two lemmas:
lemma CountInMatrixSingleColumnLemma(a: array2<int>, x: int, y: int, value: int)
  requires 0 <= x < a.Length1
  requires 0 < y <= a.Length0
  requires AscAsc(a)
  requires a[y-1,x] < value
  ensures CountInMatrix(a, x, x + 1, 0, y, value) == y;

lemma CountInMatrixSplitRuleLemma(a: array2<int>, xlo: int, xhi: int, ylo: int, yhi: int, value: int)
  requires 0 <= xlo <= xhi <= a.Length1
  requires 0 <= ylo < yhi <= a.Length0
  requires AscAsc(a)
  ensures CountInMatrix(a, xlo, xhi, ylo, yhi, value) == CountInMatrix(a, xlo, xhi, ylo, yhi - 1, value) +
                                                         CountInMatrix(a, xlo, xhi, yhi - 1, yhi, value);

These two lemmas seem quite intuitive to me, however, no matter what I try to do, I can't seem to get Dafny to verify them.
I've tried going through the relevant literature (specifically Program Proofs by K. Rustan and M. Leino), which is how I came up with the AscAsc predicate, and have based my code mostly on the slope search which looks for the existence of a value, rather than counting everything under it.
I've also tried applying induction to prove these two lemmas, but that has not lead anywhere.
Looking through Dafny counterexamples, and peppering it with asserts has also not lead me anywhere.
Any help would be appreciated!

Why would CountInMatrixSingleColumnLemma be true? Is value greater than every value in a? If that were true then it would make sense but I don't see why it would be true if value is undetermined.

If you look at the requires for CountInMatrixSingleColumnLemma, you can see that one of the requirements is requires a[y-1,x] < value. Meaning there should be y elements < value.
I've added another precondition to CountInMatrixSingleColumnLemma which should help out.

The original definitions were fine, the problem is you have defined them recursing upward where as some of your lemmas are recursing downwards. It makes setting up induction difficult.
lemma  CountInColumnSingleColumnLemma(a: array2<int>, x: int, ylo: int, yhi: int, value: int)
  requires 0 <= x < a.Length1
  // requires 0 < y < a.Length0
  requires 0 <= ylo < yhi <= a.Length0
  requires AscAsc(a)
  requires a[yhi-1,x] < value
  decreases yhi-ylo
  ensures CountInColumn(a, x, ylo, yhi, value) == yhi-ylo
{
}

lemma  CountInColumnWholeColumn(a: array2<int>, x: int,  y: int, value: int)
  requires 0 <= x < a.Length1
  // requires 0 < y < a.Length0
  requires 0 < y <= a.Length0
  requires AscAsc(a)
  requires a[y-1,x] < value
  ensures CountInColumn(a, x, 0, y, value) == y
{
  CountInColumnSingleColumnLemma(a, x, 0, y, value);
}

lemma CountInColumnSingleColumnSumLemma(a: array2<int>, xlo: int, ylo: int, yhi: int, value: int)
  requires 0 <= xlo < a.Length1
  requires 0 <= ylo < yhi <= a.Length0
  requires AscAsc(a)
  decreases yhi-ylo
  ensures CountInColumn(a,xlo,ylo,yhi,value) == CountInColumn(a,xlo,ylo,ylo+1,value) + CountInColumn(a,xlo,ylo+1,yhi,value)
{
}

lemma CountInMatrixSingleColumnLemma(a: array2<int>, x: int, y: int, value: int)
  requires 0 <= x < a.Length1
  requires 0 < y <= a.Length0
  requires AscAsc(a)
  requires a[y-1,x] < value
  ensures CountInMatrix(a, x, x + 1, 0, y, value) == y 
  {
    CountInColumnWholeColumn(a,x, y, value);
  }


Thanks! Those seem to work wonders, do you have any idea for what I could do for CountInMatrixSplitRuleLemma?

I worked on it as well when developing those lemmas but I didn't figure it out. I did notice you had a lemma converting CountInMatrix to CounInRows however I didn't grasp the intuition because I was focused on the CountInColumns, but one idea that I had was to do a calculation chain from CountInMatrix -> CountInRows -> CountInMatrix.

Another approach would be do define versions of CountInColumns and CountInMatrix which recurse downward on yhi. Show that they are equivalent to the originals. Use them to complete the induction on their version of CountInMatrixSplitRuleLemma. Then convert back to the original CountInMatrix afterwards.
